# Ubuntu 22.04 で locale の設定変更が意図した通り反映されない

Tags: ubuntu, locale

表題にある通りlocaleを日本語表記に切り替えたいと思い、いつものように
`localectl set-locale LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8` を実行しました。
一度ログアウトしてログインしてみるとまたlocaleがPOSIXに戻ってしまいます。
localectlはちゃんと変わっていて
System Locale: LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8となっているのですがlocaleはPOSIXのまま。
これはどこを書き換えてしまったのでしょうか？今のところ.bashrcに
export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
として急場を凌いでいますが謎なんです。書き変わらない理由を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: 書き換えているのは `/etc/default/locale` です。このファイルの中身が評価されるのはシステムのブート時なので、再起動する必要があります。

Comment: 中身見てみましたが
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ja_JP:ja
となっていて再起動しても変わりませんでした。ちなみにsudo su -後はちゃんとlocalsは反映されています

Comment: 再起動した後で `echo $LANG` や `echo $LANGUAGE` を実行すると何が表示されますか？

Comment: 再起動後確認してみましたがどちらも何も返ってきません。localeはLANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
となっています。sudo su -後は
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ja_JP:ja
と返ってきます。

Comment: ええと、`locale` コマンドの結果ではなく、環境変数 `LANG` や `LANGUAGE` の値を確認していただきたいのですが。。。

Comment: 書き方が悪かったですね。どちらも空なのです。

Comment: コメント欄では改行が使えないため、特にコマンドの実行結果等は質問を直接編集して追記してください。

Comment: `grep LANG ~/.bashrc`と`grep LANG ~/.profile`それぞれの実行結果はどうなりますか？また、.bashrcや.profileについて何らかの編集を実施した覚えがあれば、その内容を教えてください。

Comment: 通常ではどちらも何も表示されません。.bashrcの方では仕方なくexport LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8を追加して急場を凌いでいる状態です。当然消すと元に戻りますが。

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-locale LANG=ja_JP.UTF8
```

を実行してみてはいかがでしょうか。
私はこの手順以外をしらないので、localectlでできない理由は分かりません。
こちらの環境は`VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"`です。

---

設定が変わらない場合、以下のファイルなど、環境変数を上書きしていないか調べてみることをお勧めします。

- /etc/bash.bashrc
- /etc/profile
- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.profile

Comment: セットして再起動してみましたが変わらずです。
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"です。

Comment: sudo update-locale LANG=ja_JP.UTF8を実行後、/etc/default/localeが存在していて値はLANG=ja_JP.UTF8ですか？

Comment: 2桁出ます。LANG=ja_JP.UTF8
LANGUAGE=ja_JP:ja
と。

Comment: grep LANG /etc/bash.bashrc、grep LANG /etc/profileともに何も返ってきません。どこを書き換えたんだろう。。。

Comment: お使いのUbuntuはデスクトップ版ではありませんか？

Comment: server版を利用しています。まだ初期設定中だったので再インストールを行おうとおもっています。皆様ありがとうございました。

Comment: 状況が見えました。私はヘッドレスサーバーでリモート操作で行っていたのですが、問題はSSHでした。AcceptEnvでLANGからLANGUAGEまですべてを設定すると無事に設定が反映されました。恐らくEnvが設定されていない環境からリモート操作しようとするとそのEnvが転送されて、設定されていない環境変数がセットされるのではないでしょうか。盲点でした。取り急ぎ報告まで。